# Eclipse Subversive new files automatically added to version control

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I use Eclipse Helios and Subversive:

```
Subversive SVN Connectors 2.2.2.I20110124-1700
org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group

Subversive SVN Team Provider (Incubation) 0.7.9.I20110207-1700
org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group
```

Eclipse and Subversive automatically add new files to version control.

But it seems that this automatic behavior is parametrized: `*.log` files are not added to version control.

Where is the **configuration** for this **automatic behavior**?

Team>SVN>Properties Configuration>Automatic properties ? But the panel is empty, the rule for the `*.log` files is not listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Eclipse

It is under Team-->Ignored Resources.

[image]

### svn:ignore property

You can set the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) property to exclude certain files/file patterns from subversion:

### subversion global settings

Subversion has globally defined excludes:
[global-ignores](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2)

> When running the svn status command, Subversion lists unversioned
>   files and directories along with the versioned ones, annotating them
>   with a ? character (see the section called “svn status”). Sometimes,
>   it can be annoying to see uninteresting, unversioned items—for
>   example, object files that result from a program's compilation—in this
>   display. The global-ignores option is a list of whitespace-delimited
>   globs which describe the names of files and directories that
>   Subversion should not display unless they are versioned. The default
>   value is `*.o` `*.lo` `*.la` `#*#` `.*.rej` `*.rej` `.*~` `*~` `.#*` `.DS_Store.`
>
> As well as svn status, the svn add and svn import commands also ignore files that match the list. You can override this option for a
>   single instance of any of these commands by using the --no-ignore
>   command-line flag. For information on more fine-grained control of
>   ignored items, see the section called “svn:ignore”.

Comment: Erf... right. Stupid question... I was searching a configuration specific to subversion... Thanks!

Comment: @njames outside of eclipse? this setting will affect the subversion provider in eclipse.

Comment: inside Eclipse. (I was searching in the configuration specific to subversion, in Eclipse)